# Reading vector values by passing the vector as argument to a function in c

Tags: c

I'm trying to read 2 vectors from a file together with their lengths ,by passing them as a reference to a function.The problem is that I receive an error of type: "Access violation writing location 0xCDCDCDCD.", when I'm trying place the values from the file into the array.

Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



void read_vectors(int **v1,int **v2,int *m,int *n)
{
    FILE *fd;
    int i;
    fopen_s(&fd,"input.txt","r");
    if(fd==NULL)
    {
        perror("Error at opening the file.\n");
        exit(2);
    }
    if(fscanf_s(fd,"%d %d",m,n)!=2)
    {
        perror("Error at reading the sizes of the arrays.");
        exit(2);
    }
    if((*v1=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*(*m)))==NULL)
    {
        perror("Error at allocating memory.\n");
        exit(2);
    }
    if((*v2=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*(*n)))==NULL)
    {
        perror("Error at allocating memory.\n");
        exit(2);
    }
    for(i=0;i<*m;i++)
    {
        if(fscanf_s(fd,"%d ",v1[i])!=1)
        {
            perror("Error at reading the numbers.\n");
            exit(2);
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<*n;i++)
    {
        if(fscanf_s(fd,"%d ",v2[i])!=1)
        {
            perror("Error at reading the numbers.\n");
            exit(2);
        }
    }
    fclose(fd);
}

void print_vector(int*v,int n)
{
    int i;
    printf("The content of the vector of size:%d is:\n",n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",v[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(int argc,char*argv[])
{
    int *v1,*v2,m,n;
    read_vectors(&v1,&v2,&m,&n);
    print_vector(v1,m);
    print_vector(v2,n);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In the `read_vectors` function `v1[i]` doesn't really mean what you think it means. Try e.g. `&(*v1)[i]` instead.

Comment: It works!Thanks a lot!

Comment: Out of topic: [don't cast malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)